# Compile only one layer files in caffe

Tags: c++, makefile, build, caffe

When we developed a new layer in caffe, which is `new_layer.cpp`, `new_layer.cu`, and `new.layer.hpp`, we have to recompile caffe, is it possible to compile only this new layer files, like an update to the original library, or we have to recompile the whole library again? Can someone give me a hint?

ADD: actually I downloaded the layer files from someone's implementation on github: https://github.com/farmingyard/ShuffleNet there are `.cpp` `.cu` `.hpp` files, I put `.cpp` and `.cu` in `caffe/src/caffe/layers`, put `.hpp` in `caffe/include/caffe/layers/`, then add in `caffe.proto` as:

```
message LayerParameter {
...
optional ShuffleChannelParameter shuffle_channel_param = 164;
}
```

also:

```
message ShuffleChannelParameter {
  optional uint32 group = 1[default = 1]; // The number of group
}
```

at the end of proto file, then I call `make clean` and then `make all` in the caffe root directory, with no error and I checked there is lines of

```
CXX src/caffe/layers/shuffle_channel_layer.cpp
```

and

```
NVCC src/caffe/layers/shuffle_channel_layer.cu
```

and(I dont know if this means the proto file has been recompiled)

```
CXX .build_release/src/caffe/proto/caffe.pb.cc
```

then `make proto`, which gives:

```
make: Nothing to be done for proto
```

then I called `make pycaffe`, no error prompt, compile successfully. Then I used the example prototxt file written by the author for a sample network using the new layer, then following error prompts:

```
Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "shuffle_channel_param".
```

the full `LayerParameter`:

```
// NOTE
// Update the next available ID when you add a new LayerParameter field.
//
// LayerParameter next available layer-specific ID: 147 (last added: recurrent_param)
message LayerParameter {
  optional string name = 1; // the layer name
  optional string type = 2; // the layer type
  repeated string bottom = 3; // the name of each bottom blob
  repeated string top = 4; // the name of each top blob

  // The train / test phase for computation.
  optional Phase phase = 10;

  // The amount of weight to assign each top blob in the objective.
  // Each layer assigns a default value, usually of either 0 or 1,
  // to each top blob.
  repeated float loss_weight = 5;

  // Specifies training parameters (multipliers on global learning constants,
  // and the name and other settings used for weight sharing).
  repeated ParamSpec param = 6;

  // The blobs containing the numeric parameters of the layer.
  repeated BlobProto blobs = 7;

  // Specifies whether to backpropagate to each bottom. If unspecified,
  // Caffe will automatically infer whether each input needs backpropagation
  // to compute parameter gradients. If set to true for some inputs,
  // backpropagation to those inputs is forced; if set false for some inputs,
  // backpropagation to those inputs is skipped.
  //
  // The size must be either 0 or equal to the number of bottoms.
  repeated bool propagate_down = 11;

  // Rules controlling whether and when a layer is included in the network,
  // based on the current NetState.  You may specify a non-zero number of rules
  // to include OR exclude, but not both.  If no include or exclude rules are
  // specified, the layer is always included.  If the current NetState meets
  // ANY (i.e., one or more) of the specified rules, the layer is
  // included/excluded.
  repeated NetStateRule include = 8;
  repeated NetStateRule exclude = 9;

  // Parameters for data pre-processing.
  optional TransformationParameter transform_param = 100;

  // Parameters shared by loss layers.
  optional LossParameter loss_param = 101;

  // Layer type-specific parameters.
  //
  // Note: certain layers may have more than one computational engine
  // for their implementation. These layers include an Engine type and
  // engine parameter for selecting the implementation.
  // The default for the engine is set by the ENGINE switch at compile-time.
  optional AccuracyParameter accuracy_param = 102;
  optional ArgMaxParameter argmax_param = 103;
  optional BatchNormParameter batch_norm_param = 139;
  optional BiasParameter bias_param = 141;
  optional ConcatParameter concat_param = 104;
  optional ContrastiveLossParameter contrastive_loss_param = 105;
  optional ConvolutionParameter convolution_param = 106;
  optional CropParameter crop_param = 144;
  optional DataParameter data_param = 107;
  optional DropoutParameter dropout_param = 108;
  optional DummyDataParameter dummy_data_param = 109;
  optional EltwiseParameter eltwise_param = 110;
  optional ELUParameter elu_param = 140;
  optional EmbedParameter embed_param = 137;
  optional ExpParameter exp_param = 111;
  optional FlattenParameter flatten_param = 135;
  optional HDF5DataParameter hdf5_data_param = 112;
  optional HDF5OutputParameter hdf5_output_param = 113;
  optional HingeLossParameter hinge_loss_param = 114;
  optional ImageDataParameter image_data_param = 115;
  optional InfogainLossParameter infogain_loss_param = 116;
  optional InnerProductParameter inner_product_param = 117;
  optional InputParameter input_param = 143;
  optional LogParameter log_param = 134;
  optional LRNParameter lrn_param = 118;
  optional MemoryDataParameter memory_data_param = 119;
  optional MVNParameter mvn_param = 120;
  optional ParameterParameter parameter_param = 145;
  optional PoolingParameter pooling_param = 121;
  optional PowerParameter power_param = 122;
  optional PReLUParameter prelu_param = 131;
  optional PythonParameter python_param = 130;
  optional RecurrentParameter recurrent_param = 146;
  optional ReductionParameter reduction_param = 136;
  optional ReLUParameter relu_param = 123;
  optional ReshapeParameter reshape_param = 133;
  optional ROIPoolingParameter roi_pooling_param = 8266711;
  optional ScaleParameter scale_param = 142;
  optional SigmoidParameter sigmoid_param = 124;
  optional SmoothL1LossParameter smooth_l1_loss_param = 8266712;
  optional SoftmaxParameter softmax_param = 125;
  optional SPPParameter spp_param = 132;
  optional SliceParameter slice_param = 126;
  optional TanHParameter tanh_param = 127;
  optional ThresholdParameter threshold_param = 128;
  optional TileParameter tile_param = 138;
  optional WindowDataParameter window_data_param = 129;
  optional ShuffleChannelParameter shuffle_channel_param = 164;
}
```

Comment: @Shai, pls see my new edit

Comment: @Shai, turns out I was using another old previously compiled caffe, not the newly compiled one:)

Comment: im trying to compile roi pooling layer too into my caffe. i copied everything but it doesnt compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling using `make`, `make` knows what source it already compiled and what changed since the last build. If you only make local changes, `make` will only compile/link the source that changed and what is affected by it (A change to a header file might require compilation of other sources that `#include` this header).
That is, you do not need to do anything special, just keep using `make`.
If you `make clean` you delete all compiled objects and forces `make` to re-compile the entire project from scratch.

Comment: Thank you, I tried `make` without `make clean`, and the new layer was compiled with no error, but when I tried to use it, prompts `Message type "caffe.LayerParameter" has no field named "new_layer_param"` error, how can I check it was compiled successuflly?

Comment: @K.Wanter have you made changes to `caffe.proto` as well?

Comment: do you mean like add `message LayerParameter {
...
optional ShuffleChannelParameter shuffle_channel_param = 164;
...
}` and `message ShuffleChannelParameter {
  optional uint32 group = 1[default = 1]; // The number of group
}` in `caffe_proto`

Comment: actually I downloaded someone's implementation, `https://github.com/farmingyard/ShuffleNet`, put `.cpp` and `.cu` in `caffe/src/caffe/layers`, put `.hpp` in `caffe/include/caffe/layers/`, and then add the above two block of code in caffe.proto, then called the make command

Comment: @K.Wanter yes. if you changed `caffe.proto` you need to verify that `make` also runs the `protoc` compiler.

Comment: @K.Wanter "when I tired to use it": how exactly are you "using" it? it is possible you need to run `make tools` or some other `make`s to compile additional components.

Comment: I tried to load the layer with a prototxt network definition file like regular usage.

Comment: what do you mean runs the protoc compiler?

Comment: do you mean, in addition to run `make` in caffe root directory, I also need to compile the `caffe.proto` file?

Comment: @K.Wanter try `make proto` and `make pycaffe`

Comment: `make proto` gives `make: Nothing to be done for proto `

Comment: @K.Wanter do you have `new_layer_param` definition in your `caffe.proto`? if your layer uses `new_layer_param` data structure you need to define it somewhere and `caffe.proto` is usually the place where these things are defined.

Comment: I have edited the details, could you pls take a look?

Comment: This answer is marked as accepted, however the comments section don't make it clear if `make protoc` solved the issue, or were there further steps!